# ER Diagram: Table with no relationships

Tags: entity-relationship

Can I have a table in my ER diagram which is not connected and does not have any relationships with the other tables?

Comment: Not a question for stack overflow, but yes you can have tables not related to anything in an ERD.

Comment: Posted on here because I saw other questions about ER diagrams.Cool, thanks

Comment: ER diagrams consist of entities, relationships and attributes, not tables. If your diagram has tables and FK constraints, it's a table diagram.